# Highlight Selected Item in CollectionView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to hightlight selected item of collectionview with different color. The code works fine in iOS, but in Android it doesn't work. In Android, the first item is always selected but it doesn't hightlight the other items when I click them.

**Update**

I found the issue is GestureRecognizers on the Grid, If I remove that. It behavious as expected. After adding GestureRecognizers, the expected behavior is lost.

**Workaround**

If I wrap the Grid inside SwipeView, it works fine. However, the problem still remain when CollectionView has more than 100 items.

**2nd Workaround**

This worked nicely for any number of items in the CollectionView. Add second Grid inside the 1st Grid and apply GestureRecognizers event on the 2nd Grid and everythings works smoothly and as expected.

Theme.xaml -> getting styles from the theme file

```
<Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="ItemTemplateGrid">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualState Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource BackgroundSecondaryColorDark}, Light={StaticResource BackgroundSecondaryColorLight}}"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

XAML Page Resource

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AndroidAyaItemTemplate">
            <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto" Style="{DynamicResource ItemTemplateGrid}">
                <Grid Grid.Row="0" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto" RowSpacing="0" Padding="10">
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.ShowEnglishVerseNumber,
                                                Source={x:Reference MyPage}, Converter={StaticResource InverterBooleanConverter}}">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="{Binding ArabicText.Aya}" FontSize="{Binding BindingContext.ActiveArabicFont.FontSize, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
                                          FontFamily="{Binding BindingContext.ActiveArabicFont.FontPath, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"/>
                                <Span Text="{Binding ArabicText.ArabicAyaNumber,  StringFormat='﴿{0}﴾'}"
                                          FontSize="{Binding BindingContext.ActiveArabicFont.FontSize, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
                                          FontFamily="Sherzad"></Span>
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.ShowEnglishVerseNumber, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="{Binding ArabicText.Aya}" FontSize="{Binding BindingContext.ActiveArabicFont.FontSize, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
                                          FontFamily="{Binding BindingContext.ActiveArabicFont.FontPath, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"/>
                                <Span Text="﴿" FontSize="35" FontFamily="Sherzad"></Span>
                                <Span Text="{Binding ArabicText.AyaNumber, Converter={StaticResource ZeroToEmptyConverter}}" FontSize="Small"></Span>
                                <Span Text="﴾" FontSize="35" FontFamily="Sherzad"></Span>
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="0,5,0,5"
                            IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.ShowTransliteration, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
                               FontSize="{Binding BindingContext.TransliterationFontSize, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
                               Text="{Binding ArabicText.Transliteration}"
                            FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                    </Label>
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                            IsVisible ="{Binding BindingContext.TranslationVisible, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
                            FontSize="{Binding BindingContext.ActiveTranslationFont.FontSize, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
                            FontFamily="{Binding BindingContext.ActiveTranslationFont.FontPath, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
                            Text="{Binding AyaTranslation}"
                            FlowDirection="{Binding BindingContext.ActiveTranslationLanguage.FlowDirection, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"/>
                </Grid>
                <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Style="{DynamicResource HLine}" IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.ShowHorizentalLine, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"/>
                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="2" Command="{Binding BindingContext.ShareAyaCommand,Source={x:Reference itemView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" Command="{Binding BindingContext.NextChapterCommand, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"/>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" Command="{Binding BindingContext.PreviousChapterCommand, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"/>
                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

CollectionView

```
<CollectionView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ArabicListText}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAya}" SelectionMode="Single" FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AndroidAyaItemTemplate}"
                        x:Name="itemView">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="5"/>
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                </CollectionView>
```

If I remove the style "ItemTemplateGrid" from the Grid, it highlights every row accordingly, but the color is the default color of OS.

There is no need for SwipeView. It should work without boths workarounds.

Comment: you are using SelectionMode="Single"

Comment: Yeah, I want only one item should be selected at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you had used the **SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAya}"** , you could define a property in the model which bind the backgroundcolor of the `DataTemplate` so that you don't need to use style dictionary any more .

#### in your model

Add a property

```
private Color bgColor;
public Color BgColor
{
    get => bgColor;
    set
    {
        if (bgColor!= value)
        {
            bgColor= value;

            foreach(YourModel model in ArabicListText)
            {
                if(mdoel == SelectedAya)
                {
                    if(App.Current.RequestedTheme== OSAppTheme.Dark)
                    {
                        model.BgColor = xxx;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        model.BgColor = xxx;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    model.BgColor = xxx;
                }
            }            

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BgColor));
        }
    }
}
```

#### in DataTemplate

```
 <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto"  BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}"  Padding="10">
```

#### in Code Behind(ViewModel)

```
private YourModel selectedAya;
public YourModel SelectedAya
{
    get => selectedAya;
    set
    {
        if (selectedAya!= value)
        {
            selectedAya= value;

            

            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedAya));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution is fine, however, in my situation, the for loop for every selection seems inapproperiate and performance issue.

Comment: I will confirm if it is an existing issue on Android. You could use my solution as workaround . If it helps you , don't forget to accept it , which will help more people who has similar issue :)

Comment: Hold previously selected item in a property and when selection changes revert the previous ones background only (and set your new selection as previous). So you do not need to go all list. Hope you get the idea.